# Blog Pagination not working

Tags: octobercms

Blog Pagination is not working.

I have 2 test posts. I set pagination to 1 post per page.

It displays all posts on the first page, and creates pagination buttons.

Clicking pagination buttons changes the url but posts and pages remain the same.

---

[image: url]

---

[image: post list]

---

**HTML**

```
{# Blog Post List #}
<ul class="post-list">
    {% for post in filteredPosts %}
    <li>
        <h3><a href="/blog/{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>

        <p class="info">
            Posted
            <!--{% if post.categories.count %} in {% endif %}
            {% for category in post.categories %}
                <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.name }}</a>{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}-->
            on {{ post.published_at|date('M d, Y') }}
        </p>

        <p class="excerpt">{{ post.summary|raw }}</p>
    </li>
{% else %}
    <li class="no-data">{{ noPostsMessage }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>


{# Pagination #}
{% if posts.lastPage > 1 %}
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if posts.currentPage > 1 %}
            <li><a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (posts.currentPage-1) }) }}">&larr; Prev</a></li>
        {% endif %}

        {% for page in 1..posts.lastPage %}
            <li class="{{ posts.currentPage == page ? 'active' : null }}">
                <a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): page }) }}">{{ page }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}

        {% if posts.lastPage > posts.currentPage %}
            <li><a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (posts.currentPage+1) }) }}">Next &rarr;</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

---

**PHP**

Category Filter

```
use RainLab\Blog\Models\Post as BlogPost;

function onStart(){
    //This is where you list the categories you want to display
    $categories = ['blog'];
    $posts = [];
    foreach(BlogPost::all() as $blog){
        foreach($blog->categories as $cat){
            if(in_array($cat->slug, $categories)) {
                array_push($posts, $blog);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
   $this['filteredPosts'] = $posts;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are overriding `posts`with your custom data `filteredPosts` and your custom data is not respecting pagination

```
{% set posts = blogPosts.posts %} 
{% for post in posts %}
```

this is a loop which is iterate through all the posts in normal case it is looking like this

> In your case its

```
{% for post in filteredPosts %}
```

you see `posts` comes from the `plugin component itself` but you are `overriding it` with your data `filteredPosts`

```
function onStart(){
    //This is where you list the categories you want to display
    $categories = ['blog'];
    $posts = [];
    foreach(BlogPost::all() as $blog){
        foreach($blog->categories as $cat){
            if(in_array($cat->slug, $categories)) {
                array_push($posts, $blog);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
   $this['filteredPosts'] = $posts;
}
```

And **I don't see any `pagination logic in your code`** so it just shows the post you have in `filteredPosts` as pagination is building perfect as it uses `posts` which is passed by component.

**It seems your filter-logic is creating problem we can `use built-in filter logic to avoid this.`**

> Remove your logic code from the `onStart` and use a slug `/blog/:page?/:slug?`
>
> **Configuration**

[image]

> Component Default HTML / to reset it to default Just re-add component and use it or copy this code and use it

```
{% component 'blogPosts' %}
```

[image]

Now if we check URLs `https://october-plaza.com/blog/:page?/:slug`

- https://october-plaza.com/blog/1 - page 1
- https://october-plaza.com/blog/1 - page 2
- https://october-plaza.com/blog/1/food - page 1 with category filter based on -slug `food`
- https://october-plaza.com/blog/2/food - page 2 with category filter based on slug `food`

If you face any problem please comment